# Wide accents and bm

Tags: math-mode, bm

Is there a way to use the bold math macro `\bm` together with wide accents such as `\widetilde` or `\widehat`, without generating a too wide accent?

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
$\widetilde m$
$\widetilde{\mathbf m}$
$\mathbf{\widetilde m}$
$\bm{\widetilde m}$
$\widetilde{\bm m}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ugly, but there is this: `$\widetilde{\textit{\bfseries m}}$`

Comment: Indeed, both solutions, adding a new command defining a small widetilde as well as avoiding bm all together, fix my problem. However I was looking for a less manual/more robust solution, that can not be broken so easily by my coworkers.

Comment: You seem to think that the problem is caused by `bm` but that's not it: `\widetilde` exists in different sizes, and it just happens that `\bm{m}` is wide enough to make `\widetilde` choose the larger version. This would happen with any symbol/letter/whatever which is wide anough.

Comment: @campa good observation, one can play with `\widetilde{\rule{10.001pt}{3pt}}`, `10pt` gives the small one, `10.001pt` does not.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I did not realize that the width of the character has changed beyond a critical threshold due to the bm package handling bold italic fonts correctly.

Comment: An obvious followup question would be: Can I change the thresholds?